# HTML Renderer - generated PDF from HTML but couldn't add background image from stream C#

Tags: c#, pdf, html-to-pdf, html-renderer

I have generated PDF from HTML using HTML Renderer, all images are from stream

```
        var pngBinaryDataLogoLeft = File.ReadAllBytes(folderPath + "logo.png");
        var ImgDataURILogoLeft = @"data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(pngBinaryDataLogoLeft);
        html = html.Replace("[logoLeft]", ImgDataURILogoLeft);

        var pngBinaryDataBGImg = File.ReadAllBytes(folderPath + "background.png");
        var ImgDataURIBGImg = @"data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(pngBinaryDataBGImg);
        html = html.Replace("[BGImg]", ImgDataURIBGImg);

        var config = new PdfGenerateConfig();
        config.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        config.PageSize = PdfSharpPageSize.A4;

        string cssStr = File.ReadAllText(folderPath + "1.css");
        CssData css = PdfGenerator.ParseStyleSheet(cssStr);

        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, config, css);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        pdf.Save(stream, false);
        byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();

        File.WriteAllBytes(folderPath + "document.pdf", bytes);
```

In my HTML the img get replaced by stream are working fine

```
<img class="logo-left" src="[logoLeft]" />
```

But the background image doesn't work:

```
<body style="background: url('[BGImg]')">
```

I don't have the image from a URL as it's from database (saved as stream)

I also tried to add the background image first to a new PDF page like below:

```
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdf.Pages[0]);
XImage image = XImage.FromFile(bgImgPath);
gfx.DrawImage(image, x, y, width, height);
```

But then I couldn't add the content from HTML to the same page

Also tried with **iTextSharp**, couldn't work it out too.

Comment: You replace `[BGImg]` by `ImgDataURIDeanSign` instead of `ImgDataURIBGImg`. Is this by design?

Comment: I did replace [BGImg] by ImgDataURIBGImg, it was a typo sorry, (I changed some of the variable names when posting but left out this one) I've edited the code